# Views Pager, Can I change Items per page dynamically as provided input?

Tags: 7, views, paging

Is it possible to send `Items per page` limit in query string of view page url and get records according to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-alter-view-pagination-custom-pager) might help. I normally use hook_views_query_alter in order to alter my view results.